# Convert files to bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, image, file, directory, bitmap

I write this code to read files from folder in `directory(@"D:\\test\\ISIC_2020_Training_JPEG")`, then convert each file to bitmap in c#

```
foreach (string img in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\\test\\ISIC_2020_Training_JPEG"))
    Bitmap  bmp = new Bitmap(img);
```

But there is an error that appears in the last line, which is:

> Out of memory Exception

what is the problem in this code?

Comment: When using `@` strings, you don't have to escape `'\\'`.

Comment: Ok, but what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: How many files are that and how big are they?

Comment: Number of files=5704, the size between 1.42 MB to 3.3 MB

Comment: `Out of memory Exception` can be thrown when the format of the file is not correct, look at the file name in `img` when the exception is thrown and verify its a valid image.

Comment: Do you need array of bitmaps, or each bitmap can be discarded after processing?

Comment: Each bitmap can be discarded after processing

Comment: _"Each bitmap can be discarded after processing"_ I'd recommend something like DataFlow then to not have all of them open at once. Also, as Alex pointed out, you may want to filter for correct fileextension and catch the case where a file "pretends" to be a jpeg, but isn't.

Comment: @  Fildor , How can i do that?

Comment: Well, first of all: You only want jpg? Then use a pattern: [EnumerateFiles with filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_). But file extensions can be deceiving, so it's probably a good idea to add another check (see some of the answers). And finally catch exceptions, so failure of one file won't stop the others from being processed.

Comment: The other thing is: Disk I/O is slow. Filesystem lookups are slow. So, in order to have a constant workload, I'd setup a [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) pipeline: 1. Block - Read the filepaths 2. Block - Open file and Check for correct format. If Fail: send to Error pipeline, otherwise: 3. Block - create Bitmap, 4. Block - Process, 5. Block: Cleanup resources. So you can size each block in parallelism and queue length suiting your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have all jpeg files on provided directory, you could load image file in memory stream and check if everything okay when you load image in memory stream.

```
foreach (string imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\test\ISIC_2020_Training_JPEG"))
{
    Bitmap  bmp;
    byte[] buff = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imgPath);
    using(System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buff))
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `using (var bmp = new Bitmap(imgPath))`? What advantage does `MemoryStream` have? Not criticizing. Just curious.

Comment: There is the same the problem Out of memory Exception

Comment: I used "var " also the same problem

Comment: @JohnnyMopp there is no real advantage I used this example because it is easier to debug for him and to see if ms have any values and length of bytes in stream, your solution is better and simpler :)

Comment: @TJacken your code doesn't dispose the bitmap itself though. And that _is_ a real issue. The bitmap should definitely be in a `using` block too.

Comment: @zozo As was said before, this is due to one of the files you open not being a valid image. Use a try-catch to get around that, and maybe put a breakpoint in the Catch to see which file is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach would be to stream the image files so if there's a large file it won't hog up too much memory. Then check if the file is in the correct format before trying to convert to a `Bitmap`, hopefully this helps:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
Image image;
foreach (string imgFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\test\ISIC_2020_Training_JPEG"))
{
    using (Stream bmpStream = File.Open(imgFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(bmpStream);
        if (ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(image.RawFormat)) // Check it's the correct format
        {
            bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not disposing the bitmap itself. Just `using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(path)) { ... }` does the same thing, with correct disposing, in a lot less code.